# node.js Addons using the cocoa framework

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, node.js

I would like to use some of the c++ frameworks offered in cocoa to use with in the  node.js addon system.

If say for example how would you get the mouse position at the os level in node.js on a mac if you can not use the cocoa frameworks in a node.js addon.

If there is a way to link it up could someone please provide help in how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa is written in ObjC isn't it? That way you might just be able to use it with [NodObjC](https://github.com/TooTallNate/NodObjC).

If you are looking to integrate C++ your goto source of knowledge is node core's [Nan](https://github.com/nodejs/nan).

new implementations do that with C++ deps like [here](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs/blob/master/src/mouse.c) for desktop automation.